# How to use perl rmtree tree to remove a directory if it contains a certain file?

Tags: perl

i am trying to remove all directory's on a given a path, if they contain a certain file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Path qw( rmtree );

find(\&rm_errors, $_) for @ARGV;

sub rm_errors{
     if ($_ eq "git_errors.txt"){
     my $path = $File::Find::dir;
     rmtree( $path );
     } 
 }
```

Finding the directory's that contain the files is working but, rmtree is not deleting the directory. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Perl can probably tell you why: `rmtree($path) or die "Cannot rmtree '$path' : $!"`  That is, include the `$!` error reporting variable in a die statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the immediate question that you are asking, the way to find out what the problem is is to use a diagnostic `die` statement:

```
rmtree($path) or die "Cannot rmtree '$path' : $!";
```

That way, you will learn what error the system reports.

However, there is another issue as well. You are affecting the file system while iterating through it, which is not an excellent idea. Something like this would perhaps be better:

```
my @dirs;
find(sub { push @dirs, $File::Find::dir if $_ eq "git_errors.txt" }, $_) for @ARGV;
for my $path (@dirs) {
    rmtree($path) or die "Cannot rmtree '$path' : $!";
}
```

Which is to say, find the directories first, then delete them.

Comment: Need to be careful with `rmtree(...) or die ...` because the traversal order of File::Find may find and add a parent directory to @dirs before a child directory is found and added. Later, the parent will be deleted and then the child will not exist when its entry in @dirs is deleted. Maybe the `sub{}` in the find call should prune the search as well as adding the found directory.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Good point. You can also just change `die` to `warn`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, find changes the directory to traverse the file system.

(from perldoc: Additionally, for each directory found, it will chdir() into that directory and continue the search, invoking the &wanted function on each file or subdirectory in the directory.)

This means that, in addition to trying to modify the structure you're traversing, you're in the directory your're trying to delete.

I don't think that works from the command line either.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened with me too.
MY code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Path;
my $BASE_DIR="/sandeepr/_temp/";
my $f=strftime '%Y-%m-%d',localtime(time() - 24*60*60*60);
print "$f\n";
my $dir_to_be_cleaned=$BASE_DIR.$f;
print $dir_to_be_cleaned;
rmtree($dir_to_be_cleaned);
```

the code runs fine when it is run with sudo permission else bash will throw permission error.

on executing the above code you will get either

Comment: The code above cleans up all direcotories inside /sandeepr/_temp/(60 days older). you can also append your own file name to that and clean up the directory.